# why is SVM a "black box" learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm going through Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera, and in the intro to his section on SVM's he says: "SVMs are considered by many to be the most powerful 'black box' learning algorithm"

He doesn't elaborate on that. Why would SVM's be considered a black box? Is it because their behavior is less straightforward than that of, say, logistic regression?

Comment: related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22335/why-are-machine-learning-models-called-black-boxes http://www.ijfis.org/journal/view.html?doi=10.5391/IJFIS.2016.16.1.27

Answer (score 2):

In machine learning, some algorithms are referred to as black box processes because the mechanism that transforms the input into the output is obfuscated by an imaginary box, without interference from the audience.

In general, the fundamental problem that SVMs try to solve is binary classification. One of the classical examples is to distinguish spam emails vs non-spam emails.

The main idea behind a SVM is that it's trying to find a hyperplane separating those points in space, with the positive examples on one side, and the negative examples on the other.

This is where the idea of "machine" comes into the name. Imagine attaching a spring to each of the points that's the closest to the separating hyperplane, and the other end of the spring to the hyperplane. Those points are called "support vectors" and they act like a "machine", moving the hyperplane to the orientation that maximizes the separation between the positive and negative examples in space.

[image: SVM]